# group-by by multiple keys in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How to group a collection of maps by multiple keys?

For example:

```
(def m1 [{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
         {:a 1 :b 2 :c 4}
         {:a 1 :b 4 :c 3}
         {:a 1 :b 4 :c 3}])

(group-by-x [:a :b] m1)
```

I'd like to return this:

```
[{:a 1 :b 2} [{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}{:a 1 :b 2 :c 4}],
 {:a 1 :b 4} [{:a 1 :b 4 :c 3}{:a 1 :b 4 :c 3}]]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
(group-by #(select-keys % [:a :b]) m1)
```

This returns a map:

```
{{:b 2, :a 1} [{:a 1, :c 3, :b 2} {:a 1, :c 4, :b 2}],
 {:b 4, :a 1} [{:a 1, :c 3, :b 4} {:a 1, :c 3, :b 4}]}
```

To get exactly the return value you specified, wrap it in `(vec (apply concat ...))`:

```
(vec (apply concat (group-by #(select-keys % [:a :b]) m1)))
; => as in the question text
```

This is equivalent, but perhaps prettier:

```
(->> (group-by #(select-keys % [:a :b]) m1)
     (apply concat)
     vec)
```

Comment: You can also `(group-by (juxt :a :b) coll)`, which gives you pairs instead of maps as the keys. Often this will be a more useful format than having dozens of maps with `:a` and `:b` keys, but that depends entirely on your application.

Comment: @amalloy: Right. That was what I wrote before realizing the spec calls for a map. Agreed on vectors being quite possibly more useful, I should have included it in the answer... Thanks for fixing this glaring omission. :-)

Comment: @MichałMarczyk from what I understand "select-keys" returns a map and maps do not guarantee ordering. I think it might cause issues, don't you think?